# Discrete spectra of generators of compact Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-mechanics

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/39214/46753) answer on Phys.SE about reasons for the "discreteness" in quantum mechanics, the author mentioned

> The discrete spectrum for Lie algebra generators of a compact Lie group, e.g. angular momentum operators.

I have taken a course in Lie groups and Lie algebras (though with applications to physics), but I cannot remember proving this fact. Since we're dealing with quantum mechanics, we're probably only concerned with unitary (projective?) representations of Lie groups.

Please could someone provide a proof of this statement? Bonus points if you can provide some connection to operators in quantum mechanics!

### Attempt at a precise formulation of the question

Consider a compact Lie group $G$ and a Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}$ which generates $G$ via the usual exponential map. We can choose a basis $\{T_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ of $\mathcal{L}$, which we refer to as the *generators* of $\mathcal{L}$. Consider a representation $\rho : \mathcal{L} \rightarrow \mathrm{End}(\mathcal{H})$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

**Question:** Is the spectrum of the operator $\rho(T_{i})$ discrete?

**Bonus question:** Suppose $\mathcal{L}$ is equipped with a nondegenerate bilinear form (take the Killing form for concreteness), so given a basis $\{T_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ of $\mathcal{L}$ we can canonically define a basis $\{T^{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ of the dual space $\mathcal{L}^{*}$. Define the quadratic Casimir $\Omega = \sum_{i=1}^{n} T^{i} T_{i}$. Given the representation $\rho$ defined above, we define the Casimir invariant $\rho(\Omega) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \rho(T^{i}) \rho(T_{i})$. If $G$ is a compact Lie group, is the spectrum of the operator $\rho(\Omega)$ also discrete?

Comment: @DietrichBurde So it is not generally true that the spectrum of a generator of a compact Lie group is discrete? Are there any conditions under which this is true?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is true that the author didn't mention Lie group representations, though I think this is implicit -- we consider how these operators act on the Hilbert space of quantum states.

Comment: There are some problems with the terminology. Generators of Lie algebras in Lie algebra theory are abstract elements of the vector space, which need not be operators, so there need not be a spectrum. In physics this means something different; but certainly you have not formulated any clear question. I guess, you want to know why the differential operators associated have a discrete spectrum.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, that is what I mean -- thank you for the clarification. Is there a general answer to that question?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have edited the question. I hope this makes it clear what I'm asking, but please let me know if you need me to be any more precise.

Comment: If the Hilbert space is finite dimensional… how could the spectra fail to be discrete?

Comment: Right you are... I suppose the interesting case is when $\mathcal{H}$ is infinite-dimensional then.

Comment: If the group $G$ is $S^1$, then the Lie algebra $L$ is just $\mathbb R$, and a represenation $\rho:L\to End(H)$ (notice it is End and not GL…) can have image whatever operator you want, with spectrum as ugly as you will)

Comment: Hm, good point. Is there any sense in which the statement I linked to is true, at least under certain conditions? I am interested in applications to quantum mechanics, so perhaps we have some additional restrictions (though I am not sure what).

Comment: On the other hand, if the represenation of the Lie algebra arises from a representation of the group by differentiation, and the latter is unitary (which is probably what you want in your context) then this follows from the Peter—Weyl theorem that asserts that $H$ is a direct sum of finite dimensional reps.

Comment: @Mariano, I think that is exactly the sort of logic I was looking for. If you write your comment as an answer (possibly a bit fleshed out -- I am quite rusty on this topic, as you might be able to tell...), then I will accept it.

Comment: @Mariano, would a similar reasoning also apply to the quadratic Casimir?

Comment: The Casimir operator preserves the decomposition of $H$ as a (completed) direct sum of finite dimensional representations in that case, so its spectrum is just as discrete as everything else. This applies to all elements of the enveloping algebra of L, in fact.